# Vue.js triggers button unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have prepared a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/frvuw35k/

```html
<div id="app">
  <h2>Vue Event Test</h2>
  <form @submit.prevent>
    <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 input-group">
                <input v-model="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search users by Display Name"
                            @keyup.enter="doSearch">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" :disabled="!search" type="button"
                                @click.prevent="doSearch">
                            Search
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <button v-if="showButton" class="btn btn-info"
            @click.prevent="doSthElse">Do something else</button>
                </div>
            </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    search: null,
    showButton: false
  },
  methods: {
    doSearch: function(){
        console.log('do search:', this.search)
      this.showButton = true
    },
    doSthElse: function(){
        console.log('do something else')
    }
  }
})
```

This simulates something I have faced in my Vue application.

There is a second button, that is shown when a condition is meet. This condition is a result of a search, that is triggered by hitting enter key on the input.

On a second enter after the condition was meet, also if one has clicked somewhere else and put the focus back on the input, the second button is triggered...

I don't see the reason and haven't found out how to avoid it so fare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Explanation

This is caused by the browser behavior in a form.

The normal behavior is that when a user press down the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key on an input, it will submit the form.

Also, to submit a form, the browser will look for a button in the form, which is your "Do something else" button in your case.

So when the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it will trigger a button press on your last button, calling the `doSthElse` method.

### How to fix

To fix this, simply add the a `@keydown.enter.prevent` listener on the form to prevent the default behavior to trigger.

I updated your fiddle with the fix : https://jsfiddle.net/vy57d63f/

Comment: Thank you. I tried .prevent on the input, without luck but I didn't come up with the form idea...

Answer (score 1):

Use this: You need to user @keydown and prevent modifier

```
<input v-model="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search users by Display Name"
                        @keydown.enter.prevent="doSearch"/>
```

Comment: Because of your answer, I searched a bit and found a site that generally suggest to only use keydown: https://www.mutuallyhuman.com/blog/keydown-is-the-only-keyboard-event-we-need/
Any thoughts on that?

Comment: very nice article